# iSeries/AS400 progressive rollouts

Tags: ibm-midrange

We've been tasked with finding a progressive rollout of software solution.
Lets take a simple application with a data and object libraries that is currently on Version 1. We want to be able to upgrade where only certain users use Version 2, but still keep a centralised database.

I have two ideas in my head at the moment as follows:
[Phased Rollouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMUXn.png)

In Example 1, users would move from pointing to the Existing Objects to the Upgraded, eventually Existing would no longer be needed and could be removed.
In Example 2, users would move from pointing to the Existing Objects/Database to the Upgraded, eventually Existing would no longer be needed and could be removed.
Overall idea, is that the rollout of software is phased, thus de-risking the rollout. And if needed, users could just point back to existing object/database.

Do people out there do this sort of thing? Are there Source Management/Delivery tools out there that automate this?

Answer (score 1):

On IBM i, depending on the language you are using for data access, the programs ate tied very tightly to the database tables. Generally when a database update is required there are a couple ways to do it (I am assuming record level access using RPG as that is most common):

1. Promote Database update first, then programs

In this method will have to compile the programs for promotion twice!

2. Promote Database updates along with program updates

In this method you will only have to compile the programs for promotion once.

---

**First Method**

This is a good way to do things if you have a large change. In this method, you would make all of your database changes at once, and recompile all the programs that touch the changed files. This recompile is done without making any changes to the programs. If you have only added new fields to the files, this can be very easy to do. The application should work the same as it did before, but the database is ready to start making changes to populate and update the new fields.

The next step is to make necessary updates to the programs. This can be bitten off in smaller chunks now because the database changes have already been made. And you may be able to activate those changes only for specific users by using different library lists for different sets of users, though that might make the database a little inconsistent. If the phase in is for testing purposes, then it is better to use a third QA environment for testing. If you are trying to reduce risk, just make the changes small, but roll each change out to everyone all at once. If you have a CMS, it should archive your changes so you can back out a change that goes poorly.

**Second Method**

This is best for smaller changes that you can do quickly. Just make the change to the database and programs all at once, then promote everything together. If you have a CMS, this can be pretty easy, and you still have rollback capability. If you are still managing promotions manually, you can only do smaller changes this way due to the number of objects that must be changed.

**NOTE**

In either case a CMS will make your life easier. I have worked places that promote manually, and at places that have automated CMS software. The rollouts are easier, with less risk in places with a proper CMS in place. Rocket Software, Arcad, Soft Landing, and others provide CMS software for IBM i. That is the key to reducing the risk of a change.

Comment: Hi, that's a great a detailed answer. Apologies I should have specified that we use RPG (along with PFs/TABLEs) and we do use Arcad for CMS and delivery. They don't offer a phased rollout solution. I have used Turnover previously and they don't have it either (and have gone really expensive!). As you say, some sort of CMS has to be the best option, it's takes away the pain and human error. I'm sure that there is a solution for phased rollouts using CMS, as I can't imagine some of the big players (financial institutions etc) would accept a big bang install. I guess my search continues!

Comment: Phased rollout as you are thinking would not work. You would have data issues because some folks would be using old programs to update data, and others using new programs to do the same updates. Your database would become inconsistent, and that is much worse. I am telling you how fortune 500 companies do it. My experience is from there. They break the change up into manageable chunks, and do the smaller updates. Arcad does indeed handle things that way.

Comment: To do what you propose would require additional synchronization software to deal with the inconsistencies between the two databases, or the two groups of users would not have access to each other's data. This adds a lot of complexity and risk.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yeah, smaller chunks I guess would be a nice way to do it. Some of our customer don't or won't take upgrades regularly (we're talking months, and in one case a full year) so that makes things tricky. Maybe we need to "re-train" them! I do understand the issue with synchronisation, and that's the crux of the matter. How, or in fact is it possible, to synch two databases in real-time. From the sounds of things the answer unfortunately is no. Thanks for your input, it's appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are in a vendor role. You can force the issue to a point by making sure they are up to date before providing support. It is the ibm ptf model. You: i have a problem, IBM: what's your ptf level? Ahh, you are way behind. You need to install ptfs.

Comment: @johnp - The first method described in this answer *is* a phased rollout. But you have to design your phases such that you can make these steps. An "upgraded" database has to be designed so that it is compatible with the existing database. Mainly, this means the upgraded database can have new files and/or new fields, but all existing files and fields must remain, so that the existing programs can work as-is (albeit recompiled, if they are using PFs that have had fields added to them), and all existing data can be housed in the updated database. This corresponds to Example 1 in your picture.

Comment: Not saying syncing isn't possible, but it is only as good as the programs you write. You might be able to use a data integration tool. But two way sync is a pain even without transformation. No matter what db you are using.